# Bidirectional real-time sync of large file tree between two distant linux servers

Tags: linux, cluster, synchronization, lsyncd, csync2

By large file tree I mean about 200k files, and growing all the time.  A relatively small number of files are being changed in any given hour though.

By bidirectional I mean that changes may occur on either server and need to be pushed to the other, so rsync doesn't seem appropriate.

By distant I mean that the servers are both in data centers, but geographically remote from each other.  Currently there are only 2 servers, but that may expand over time.

By real-time, it's ok for there to be a little latency between syncing, but running a cron every 1-2 minutes doesn't seem right, since a very small fraction of files may change in any given hour, let alone minute.

**EDIT**: This is running on VPS's so I might be limited on the kinds of kernel-level stuff I can do.  Also, the VPS's are not resource-rich, so I'd shy away from solutions that require lots of ram (like Gluster?).

What's the best / most "accepted" approach to get this done?  This seems like it would be a common need, but I haven't been able to find a generally accepted approach yet, which was surprising.  (I'm seeking the safety of the masses. :)

I've come across [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) to trigger a sync at the filesystem change level.  That seems clever though not super common, and I'm a bit confused by the various lsyncd approaches.  There's just using lsyncd with rsync, but it seems this could be fragile for bidirectionality since rsync doesn't have a notion of memory (eg- to know whether a deleted file on A should be deleted on B or whether it's a new file on B that should be copied to A).  [lipsync](https://github.com/philcryer/lipsync) appears to be just a lsyncd+rsync implementation, right?

Then there's using lsyncd with [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/), like this: https://icicimov.github.io/blog/devops/File-system-sync-with-Csync2-and-Lsyncd/ ... I'm leaning towards this approach, but csync2 is a little quirky, though I did do a successful test of it.  I'm mostly concerned that I haven't been able to find a lot of community confirmation of this method.

People on here seem to like Unison a lot, but it seems that it is [no longer under active development](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html) and it's not clear that it has an automatic trigger like lsyncd.

I've seen [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/) mentioned, but maybe overkill for what I need?

**UPDATE:** fyi- I ended up going with the original solution I mentioned: lsyncd+csync2.  It seems to work quite well, and I like the architectural approach of having the servers be very loosely joined, so that each server can operate indefinitely on its own regardless of the link quality between them.

Comment: What kind of changes do you need to handle? E.G. creation, deletion, modification.

Comment: Also, do you expect conflicts? Could the same file be modified on both servers?

Comment: All changes: creation, deletion, modification.  There is a potential for conflicts, but they should be rare.  I wouldn't mind if I simply receive an alert on a conflict that I then have to resolve manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) in [Dual-primary](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-dual-primary-mode.html) mode with a [Proxy](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide-emb/s-drbd-proxy.html) is an option.

Comment: The Proxy appears to be neither open source nor free, right?  I'm not sure I understand the consequence of not having a Proxy in async mode: during an extended downtime, if there's no Proxy, the [small?] output buffer could fill up and we would lose the sync?  Is it hard to recover from that?

Comment: See my answer above. I don`t think the proxy is the thing you need. Even during a small downtime the drbd-meta-device will mark "dirty" blocks and will transfer them after the connection is up again. I think the main difference between proxy and async-mode is that async-mode uses a maximum buffer of some MBs. After that it syncs up befor filling the buffer again. The proxy propably allows for a bigger buffer (needed if you have big latency or can write much faster locally than remote).

Answer (score 3):

In your case I would recommend a combination of DRBD in dual-primary-mode and gfs or ocfs.

The drawback of DRBD in dual-primary is that it will be running in syncronous mode. But write-speed does not seem to be important here right?

An alternative to DRBD might be a Soft-Raid1 using many (2+) iSCSI-Targets - but I would prefer DRBD with two nodes.

Comment: Synchronous mode would be bad--I don't need it, and I wouldn't want to undermine performance since the servers are connected over a WAN across continents.  But can't you have dual-primary in async mode?

Comment: I am currently using DRBD 8.3.5 - there you have to be in sync-mode ("C") to get into dual primary mode. I have no personal experience with DRBD proxy but it seems to be similar to Veritas Volume Replicator - but this is propably not suited since you want write-access on both sides. Sync mode on block-level might not be as bad as you think - perhaps gfs and/or ocfs can buffer writes.

Comment: I just checked a [german article](http://www.linux-magazin.de/Online-Artikel/GFS2-und-OCFS2-zwei-Cluster-Dateisysteme-im-Linux-Kernel) comparing GFS2 and OCFS2. From that at least OCFS2 seems to support buffered file-system-access. GFS2 is recommended in that article since it is older. See [RedHat documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Global_File_System_2/s1-ov-lockbounce.html) on GFS2 for details about GFS2 - it uses buffering, too - but you should use different dirs for concurrent writes to get the best performance.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than syncing, why not share the same filesystem over NFS?

Comment: NFS is awful, just awful. Anything would be better than NFS

Comment: One of the main points of the multi-server setup is failover/redundancy.  So one server must be able to continue without the other.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question then - no need to vote down a perfectly reasonable answer!

Comment: fyi I didn't downvote it--somebody else did. But yes, I should have mentioned that to begin with.

Comment: @Bart: Well - he did mention that there is concurrent access on two distant sites. So even if you put up HA-NFS that would be a bad solution, since one side would suffer from latency during NFS-access.
And I did not downvote either. But I`ve been NFS admin long enough to support AliGibbs. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a distributed filesystem is probably better than hacking this together with tools and scripts, especially if the cluster of servers will grow.  You'll also be able to handle a downed node better.

I don't think Gluster (or AFS) is overkill at all.

Comment: Gluster requires 1GB ram? http://www.gluster.com/community/documentation/index.php/Gluster_3.2:_Checking_Minimum_Requirements ... I'm also on a VPS, so I'm not sure about making kernel level changes that AFS might require.  But I'm starting to see that a proper distributed fs is the better path.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't catch earlier that you were using VPS hosts.  Gluster memory footprints, both server and client, are not small and they can grow substantially.  DRBD sounds more appropriate.

Comment: AFS is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated above, many solutions are available, each with its advantages and drawbacks.

I think I would consider placing the whole tree under version control ([Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), for instance) and periodically checking in/updating from both servers in cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Having just ended somewhat of a quest regarding the same thing, I'm going with gluster. However, I haven't done or found any performance tests.